# Is there a way to customize the Heroku internal server error page?

Tags: heroku

So, Heroku has some very limited documentation on how to customize error pages but I haven’t found documentation on how to modify the internal server error page. I would like to show a custom page so users at least get some guidance on why their query did not work properly. The internal server error is extremely ambiguous.

Here is an example of what the internal server error page currently looks like on my Heroku app…
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pages displayed to your users when the application encounters a system error or is placed in the maintenance state can be customized. Customizing these pages allows you to present a more consistent UI to your users.

**Create and store the custom pages**

Create your custom pages as static HTML. You may wish to use the default HTML served by Heroku as a template:

```
https://www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html
https://www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/no-such-app.html
https://www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/maintenance-mode.html
https://www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/ssl-cert-error.html
```

You can reference images or CSS from the HTML as long as you use relative paths (for example, ) and you upload the other assets into the same place as the HTML.

You can host the pages anywhere that can serve web pages. It recommends uploading to Amazon S3. If you use S3, don’t forget to set the HTML and all assets to be publicly readable.

**Configure your application**

Set the ERROR_PAGE_URL and MAINTENANCE_PAGE_URL config vars to the publicly accessible URLs of your custom pages:

```
heroku config:set \
ERROR_PAGE_URL=//s3.amazonaws.com/<your_bucket>/your_error_page.html \
MAINTENANCE_PAGE_URL=//s3.amazonaws.com/<your_bucket>/your_maintenance_page.html
```

Refer this page : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages

Comment: So, that documentation doesn’t tell you how to change or customize the internal server error page on Heroku. My Heroku app works perfectly fine. I want to modify what users will see if the application doesn’t work correctly and it causes it to fail to load, invoking a server error, after they have attempt to do something within the application.

Comment: does the error occur due to some errors in your application logic?

Comment: Ashkar, it does. However, it also occurs due to a server overload. I want to be able to redirect a user to a page depending on whether it’s an error in the application or there are just too many requests. This way I can troubleshoot users that are having problems with my application. The current internal error page is too ambiguous. I just can’t figure out how to change it within Heroku or the application itself.

Comment: only "system errors" can be customized with an external error page "Other errors, such as application errors (a 404 or 500), will display your application’s error page and not the Heroku error page. Only system-level errors that result in no response, or a malformed one, will display the Heroku error page discussed here."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make a custom page for my first issue, I used programming logic to give user errors to preempt problems related to Heroku's Internal Server Error page when my application did not run appropriately. I highly suggest you think deeply before employing this method, as it could confuse users. The Heroku Internal Server Error page is an either-or reason code. While you know (as the programmer) only one reason code applies, since you've preempted the problem with logic, the user won't assume that. For me, it was better than the alternative - which was to leave it completely ambiguous. At least, I can give users some feedback.